# Why is kafka poll method blocking?

Tags: apache-kafka, kafka-consumer-api

Writing to Kafka is non-blocking but reading from it blocks thread. 
Why does the Kafka poll method not use non-blocking API and then receive records in a callback?

Comment: Well, it's not guaranteed to consume 500 records (max.poll.records default) in a single poll, so it waits until it can read them

Comment: My question is why it is waiting? What's the problem if it has a callback and when 500 records were ready, fire the callback.

Comment: You can write your own callback in a consumer thread , or feel free to submit a PR

Comment: This is a design reason, not just submiting PR!

Comment: I am not a Kafka committer, so if you would like to ask that, try going to the Apache Mailing list